# Regex to get string until certain string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string and I want to extract certain part of the string using regex.

Below is my script. I could able to get the expected output. But need to know do we have any alternative way to achieve this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $str = "Network=ABC,Network=10,Node=N360,Slot=3,Unit=R1,Group=RU,DeviceSet=1,Device=2";

if($str =~ m/(.*),Device/){
    print "Out: $1";
} else {
    print "Not matching";
}
```

If the string contains `Device=<anydigit>` at the end, then it should not print `Device=<anydigit>` and rest everything it should print. I am doing this using `(.*)` expression. Apart from this any alternative we have?

Comment: You can try substitution i.e. `s/,Device=.*//;`

Comment: Those strings of yours are actually comma separated key/value pairs. The most correct solution is probably not to try to parse them as strings, but to parse them as CSV.

Comment: @TLP: There is no chance of comma(`,`) in between the values in this whole string. So I can go with string matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the `Device=<N>` anywhere in the string, including at the end, you can use this replacement:

```
my $str = "Network=ABC,Network=10,Node=N360,Slot=3,Unit=R1,Group=RU,DeviceSet=1,Device=2";
$str =~ s/,Device=\d+//;
# result: "Network=ABC,Network=10,Node=N360,Slot=3,Unit=R1,Group=RU,DeviceSet=1"
```

Explanation:

- search: `,Device=\d+`
- replace: (empty, e.g. remove the match)

This regex is more defensive. If however you'd like to remove the pattern *only* at the end, append a `$` to the regex:

```
$str =~ s/,Device=\d+$//;
```

Comment: Put an anchor of that so it matches at the end of the string (And not anywhere else) and you've solved part of his problem.

Comment: @briandfoy: I actually did not add an anchor on purpose in case the `Device=<N>` is *not* at the end

Comment: Well, that's not what he wants. He specifically said "at the end". If it's not at the end, then you need to do proper CSV handling all around.

Comment: @briandfoy: Yes, it's trivial to change the rgex to `s/,Device=\d+$//` to make it more restrictive. For defensive coding I'd make it less restrivtive.

Comment: Notice that you also say "at the end", but that's not what you do or what you are saying in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "Network=ABC,Network=10,Node=N360,Slot=3,Unit=R1,Group=RU,DeviceSet=1,Device=2";

my @field_order = ( $str =~ m/(\w+)=/g);
my %value_of = ($str =~ m/(\w+)=(\w+)/g);

print Dumper \%value_of;

print "Contains Device of $value_of{'Device'}\n" if defined $value_of{'Device'};

pop ( @field_order ) if ( $field_order[-1] eq "Device" ); #discard trailing 'Device' field. 

print Dumper \@field_order;


#Splice together your hash, without including 'Device' on the end. 
print join ",", map { $_ . "=". $value_of{$_}  } @field_order;
```

In doing this you parse your string into a data structure, and can work with the separate keys and values,

Answer (score 1):

**May be this will help**

```
    if($str =~ m/(.*?)\,Device\b/){
       print "Out: $1";
    } else {
       print "Not matching";
    }
```

Here, (.*?) will find the first set string of Device word. Also, we need to set the boundary for the Word.

Comment: A non-greedy match like that at the beginning of the string doesn't help you solve this. Matching `\,Device\b` already gets you to the first instance of that. But, note that you need to match at the end of the string, not just at a word boundary,

Comment: I tried this and conveying. it will not stop in the DeviceSet.

Answer (score 1):

First, does you pattern actually match what you want? You want to find `Device=<digit>` at the end. That's not what your pattern does though. You don't include the information about the digit or the end of line. Anchors are important in these situations:

```
 /
 ,       # Start of final field to anchor this to a whole column
 Device
 =
 [0-9]
 $       # end of line
 /x
```

Second, the substitution operation tells you the number of substitutions it made. If it made a substitution, that's a line you want, so print the modified line:

```
if( $var =~ s/.../\n/ ) {
   print $var
   }
else {
   print "No match\n";
   }
```